# why is this postgresql full text search query returning ts_rank of 0?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, fuzzy-search, tsvector

Before I invest in using solr or lucene or sphinx, I wanted to try to implement a search capability on my system using postgresql full text search.

I have a national list of businesses in a table that I want to search. I created a ts vector that combines the business name and city so that I can do a search like "outback atlanta".

I am also implementing an auto-completion function by using the wildcard capability of the search by appending ":*" to the search pattern and inserting " & " between keywords, so the search pattern "outback atl" turns into the "outback & atl:*" before getting converted into a query using to_tsquery().

Here's the problem that I am running into currently.
if the search pattern is entered as "ou", many "Outback Steakhouse" records are returned.
if the search pattern is entered as "out", no results are returned.
if the search pattern is entered as "outb", many "Outback Steakhouse" records are returned.

doing a little debugging, I came up with this:

```
select ts_rank(to_tsvector('Outback Steakhouse'),to_tsquery('ou:*')) as "ou",
ts_rank(to_tsvector('Outback Steakhouse'),to_tsquery('out:*')) as "out",
ts_rank(to_tsvector('Outback Steakhouse'),to_tsquery('outb:*')) as "outb"
```

which results this:

```
ou          out   outb
0.0607927   0     0.0607927
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is this a limitation of pg full text search?

Is there something that I can do with my dictionary or configuration to get around this anomaly?

UPDATE:
I think that "out" may be a stop word.

when I run this debug query, I don't get any lexemes for "out"

```
SELECT * FROM ts_debug('english','out back outback');

alias         description       token     dictionaries      dictionary      lexemes 
asciiword     Word all ASCII    out       {english_stem}    english_stem    {}
blank         Space symbols               {}            
asciiword     Word all ASCII    back      {english_stem}    english_stem    {back}
blank         Space symbols               {}            
asciiword     Word all ASCII    outback   {english_stem}    english_stem    {outback}
```

So now I ask how do I modify the stop word list to remove a word?

UPDATE:
here is the query that I currently using:

```
select id,name,address,city,state,likes 
from view_business_favorite_count 
where textsearchable_index_col @@ to_tsquery('simple',$1) 
ORDER BY ts_rank(textsearchable_index_col, to_tsquery('simple',$1)) DESC
```

When I execute the query (I'm using Strongloop Loopback + Express + Node), I pass the pattern in to replace $1 param. The pattern (as stated above) will look something like "keyword:*" or "keyword1 & keyword2 & ... & keywordN:*"

thanks

Comment: What about using `simple` instead of `english` as the configuration?

Comment: I did switch over to simple instead of english to get this working in the interim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are searching against *business names* and as @Daniel correctly pointed out - `'english'` dictionary will not help you to find "fuzzy" match for NON-dictionary words like "Outback Steakhouse" etc;

#### `'simple'` dictionary

`'simple'` dictionary on its own will not help you neither, in your case *business names* will work only for **exact match** as all words are unstemmed.

#### `'simple'` dictionary + `pg_trgm`

But if you use `'simple'` dictionary together **with** [**`pg_trgm`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgtrgm.html) module - it will be exactly what you need, in particular:

- for `to_tsvector('simple','<business name>')` you don't need to worry about stop words "hack", you will get all the lexemes unstemmed;
- using `similarity()` from `pg_trgm` you will get the the highest "rank"
  for the best match,

look at this:

```
WITH pg_trgm_test(business_name,search_pattern) AS ( VALUES
  ('Outback Steakhouse','ou'),
  ('Outback Steakhouse','out'),
  ('Outback Steakhouse','outb')
)
SELECT business_name,search_pattern,similarity(business_name,search_pattern)
FROM pg_trgm_test;
```

result:

```
   business_name    | search_pattern | similarity 
--------------------+----------------+------------
 Outback Steakhouse | ou             |        0.1
 Outback Steakhouse | out            |       0.15
 Outback Steakhouse | outb           |        0.2
(3 rows)
```

Ordering by `similarity` `DESC` you will be able to get what you need.

#### UPDATE

For you situation there are 2 possible options.

#### Option #1.

Just create trgm index for `name` column in `view_business_favorite_count` table; index definition may be the following:

```
CREATE INDEX name_trgm_idx ON view_business_favorite_count USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

Query will look something like that:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  name,
  address,
  city,
  state,
  likes,
  similarity(name,$1) AS trgm_rank -- similarity score
FROM 
  view_business_favorite_count
WHERE 
  name % $1 -- trgm search
ORDER BY trgm_rank DESC;
```

#### Option #2.

With full text search, you need to :

- create a separate table, for example `unnested_business_names`, where you will store 2 columns: 1st column will keep *all* lexemes from `to_tsvector('simple',name)` function, 2nd column will have `vbfc_id`(FK for `id` `from view_business_favorite_count` table);
- add `trgm` index for the column, which contains lexemes;
- add trigger for `unnested_business_names`, which will update OR insert OR delete new values from `view_business_favorite_count` to keep all words up to date

Comment: I just updated the question with the actual query. How would i combine the trigram fuzzy search with the full text search?